# MomentJs generating different dates

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

when I execute the command `moment("2020-10-12 20:00","YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").utc().toString()` it returns me `Mon Oct 12 2020 23:00:00 GMT+0000`. However when I run `moment("2020-11-12 20:00","YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").utc().toString()`, it returns me `Thu Nov 12 2020 22:00:00 GMT+0000`. As you can see the time changes from 23:00 to 22:00. Why does this happen if the times are the same? And how could I arrange this so that the two of them would return to me 23:00?

I am in Brasil and using moment-timezone.

Comment: Do you have daylight savings time change between those dates?

Comment: @RubenHelsloot Brazil does not have a summer schedule, but if it did, it would start in November. Exactly the month in which the problem occurs

Comment: Do you have the moment updated? They fixed Brazilian time a while ago https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/5246

Comment: @RubenHelsloot "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",

Comment: The strings are parsed as local. Since you're in Brazil, likely daylight the first is treated as standard time (UTC -3) and the second as daylight saving time (UTC -2). However, Brazil isn't observing daylight saving from 2020 onward. If you want both to be treated as having the same offset, then add an offset to the string before parsing and include it in the parse tokens.

Comment: @honza—likely this has nothing to do with moment.js, which uses the built–in Date functionality. It's more likely the host that has the wrong offset data and moment.js just using that.